# How to find the row with the highest element in a matrix

Tags: python

I write code to create a lower triangular matrix using Gaussian elimination, in python. As per now I've written a section to find the row with the highest value in a specific column, but it keeps returning the wrong value and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. This is my code so far:

```
A = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
            [3, 1, 0],
            [2, 1, 0]], dtype = float)

n = len(A)

for i in range(0, n):
    max_element = abs(A[i][i])
    max_row = i
    for k in range(i+1, n):
        if abs(A[k][i]) > max_element:
            max_element = abs(A[k][I])
            max_row = k
```

Could anyone help me with suggestion, how to fix it please?

Comment: What is your desired output? `3`?

Comment: Please, specify what you receive, and what you'd like to receive - then it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: `abs(A[k][I])` should be `abs(A[k][i])`

Comment: `print(A.max())` ?

Comment: `np.max(np.abs(A))` will get the largest absolute value and `np.argmax(np.max(np.abs(A), axis=1))` will get the corresponding row index.

Comment: When I use np.max(np.abs(A)) it returns 3 (the correct value) but then when I go on to np.argmax(np.abs(A), axis = 0) it returns [1, 0, 0]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
            [3, 1, 0],
            [2, 1, 0]], dtype = float)

print(A[A.max(axis = 1).tolist().index(A.max()),:])
```

Output `array([3., 1., 0.])`

Which is the row with 3 present.

Let me know if you need explanation of any part.

Comment: I get an error for invalid syntax for the colon at the end but when I remove this I get [1] which is the index of the row with the maximum element which is what I want so is this okay to use or is it just coincidence that it returns the right answer in this case?

Comment: @m0729 Are you sure you are using the A at the starting of the line?